# SurfaceView will never fill when preview camera2?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, surface, android-camera2

I use `SurfaceView` to preview camera with `camera2` api. But it always partial black as follow pic.

My xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <TextView
            android:text="Egos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="record"/>

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Partial Callback.

```
mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = holder;
        try {
            tryPre();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Pre Method.

```
private void tryPre() throws CameraAccessException {
    if (mSurfaceHolder == null) {
        return;
    }
    // mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(1080, 1530); // no use
    List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(1);
    Surface surface = mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();
    outputSurfaces.add(surface);
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(surface);
    final int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                session.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(),
                        captureCallback, mHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        }
    }, mHandler);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <TextView
        android:text="Egos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/captureImage"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_video_away"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```